# How to get Ldap working on localhost on xampp?

Tags: php, xampp, ldap, windows-10

I have a issue where on my localhost (running on XAMPP) I get the below error **"Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server..."**

The same code works on the dev server. I have the same code and when i try running the application on my localhost (using XAMPP), it gives me the error.

I tried the below steps I found online:-

1. The xampp\php directory has the following files

   - libeay32.dll
   - libsasl.dll
   - ssleay32.dll
2. I uncommented the ldap extension in the php.ini (xampp\php\php.ini) file to below

   - ```
     extension=php_ldap.dll
     ```
3. Restarted the server
4. xampp\php directory path is also in system environment variable PATH.
5. phpinfo shows that LDAP is enabled.

Still, not working. Any idea why from localhost it may not work?

Edit: Adding Code

```
    $hostname = "**********";
    $port = 636;
    $bindDN = "cn=*** ***,ou=binds,dc=***,dc=*******,dc=***";
    $bindPassword = "********";
    if ($conn = ldap_connect('ldaps://' . $hostname . ':' . $port)) {
       if (!ldap_bind($conn, $bindDN, $bindPassword)) {
          return null;
       }
       else {
            return $conn;
       }
    }
```

Comment: It can't connect to the server you are specifying. What's the code look like? Is the LDAP server running?

Comment: @JasonK Hi, well the code put in the body above, also same code though works from the Development server. So it should be running...right? The problem only with my local machine, where i checkout the code and was running the application. Again using XAMPP localhost.

Comment: If your trying to connect to a remote server. Does that server allow remote connections?

Comment: ok, i will verify that. Thanks

Comment: That should include checking any firewalls between localhost and the server...